# What is the reasonable value for the contract wasm size limit on parachains?

Tags: ink

What is the reasonable value for the contract `code_len` limit on parachains? The default size limit is 128 KiB now, but do you think the value will be decreased or increased?

I'm working on relatively large contracts, so the limit can affect the design of the contracts.

Limit: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/monthly-2022-02/frame/contracts/src/schedule.rs#L504

Possibly related: https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/9354

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The default limit of 128KiB is rather arbitrary and was chosen in a time before parachains were implemented. True sharding and contracts is something that is hard to bring together. The limit on a production chain will not be necessarily smaller than it is now. However, it will most likely be uneconomical to use contracts that are 128KiB in size once the a chain approaches its transaction limit. To answer your question: This limit most likely won't going up in the near future. Note that the so called [code merkelization](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/9431) will enable bigger contracts but as of now it is unclear when this will happen.

A good limit to aim for would be 24KiB which is the original code size limit on Ethereum. That said, even many of the ink! example contracts are above this limit and this is mostly by overhead incurred by the ink! codegen itself. The ink! team is in the process of removing this overhead: [1](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/1134) [2](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/issues/990) [3](https://github.com/paritytech/ink/pull/1111)

If your contract is already hitting the 128KiB limit you should make an effort to keep the size down. While some of the size is caused by current limitations of ink! itself (as described above) there are some things you can do right now:

- Make sure to pass `--release` to `cargo contract`. This will remove debug output which contributes a lot to size and should not be used for production contracts.
- Make sure to not add any heavy dependencies to your contract. While cargo makes it easy to add new dependencies it will most likely bloat your contract because most crates are not optimized for size. For example, depending on a cryptographic crate is common trap that developers tap into. If you really must do crypto in your contract (often you think you do but in reality you don't) you should use [`self.env().ecdsa_recover()`](https://paritytech.github.io/ink/ink_lang/struct.EnvAccess.html#method.ecdsa_recover) instead.
- Don't use strings in your contract. Anything human readable should live in the UI and not in a contract.